# HTML Open outlook new mail on button click (Attachment/HTML body)

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

I need to open outlook when clicking a button on a webpage.
It must create a new mail with prepopulated fields.

Here's my problem :
The mail body must contain some dynamically generated HTML.

I tried with a mailto but apparently it can only contain plaintext.

What other solution do I have ? (The mail can't be sent server side because the mail must come from client mail address).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: where you get stuck...? show some efforts you've done..

Answer (score 1):

mailto only works with plaintext.

For Outlook users you can create your own oft-file and offer a download.

See this example (Just follow the 5 steps)
http://apps.devryeducationgroup.com/brandguidelines/devryuniversity/email-templates.htm

Your second option would be:

Just ask for the customers-email address, and sent him the full email with populated fields as an email. Then he just has to click "answer" and you get the information beeing send from the customers email adress.

(Like saying, "thx for contacting us, please confirm your request by answering this mail")